# How do I create my own floor function in C?

Tags: c

I'm creating a program which will take the day, month and year from the user and then display that in three different formats, a calendar format, an ordinal format and in the ISO weekday number. In order to calculate the ordinal day, my provided pseudocode states that I need to calculate it using the floor function. However, I need to create my own and cannot use the standard one in the C library. Obviously there's more than this to the program but I'm stuck on this particular part.

I've got no idea where to start with it, and I'm not sure if I'm overcomplicating it or not. I had a look at what the floor function does, and I understood that it returns the value of something to the nearest integer as long as it is equal to or less than the original value. I was thinking of creating it with three arguments since that's how many it takes in the algorithm, and then perhaps use rounding to the nearest integer but then insert a conditional to round down if the answer of floor will be greater than the original value.

My pseudo-code looks like this:

```
int calculate_ordinal_day(day, month, year)
    if month = 1; {
       return day;
    }
    if month = 2; {
       return day + 31;
    }
    ordinal_day = myfloor(30.6 * month - 91.4) + day
    {
    if isyearleap == 1
       return ordinal_Day + 60
    }
    return ordinal_day + 59
```

By the way, my course expects to use Ansi C / K&R, which is why some of it may be different to what everyone else uses.

Comment: Your question is about writing a `floor` function, but the code given does not reflect your attempts to create such function.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be `float myFloor(float value) { return (float) (int) value; }`…

Comment: @usr2564301 i'm not sure if that method would cover everything that floor does, as i've had a look at a few examples of peoples implementations of it and they seemed pretty complex, as well as, i'm not entirely sure how to turn it from words into code

Comment: Also, what do you expect `if month = 1; {...}` and `if month - 2; {...}` to do?

Comment: You have semicolons where they should not be, and no semicolons where they should be.

Comment: Your if statements need parentheses and you need to use `==` to test for equality. A single `=` will assign a value, not test for it.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons the month = 1, month = 2 are the months that the user inputs at the start, in the pseudocode they're shown as January and February, but the user inputs them in a number format rather than in words so i've just converted them for usage later on.

Comment: You show `int calculate_ordinal_day(day, month, year)` — that's a horrid piece of C, and not valid in C99, let alone C11 or C18.  You've implicitly declared the variables `day`, `month` and `year` to be of type `int`.  Use a proper function prototype, not the K&R-style function definition — and conform to at least C99: `int calculate_ordinal_day(int day, int month, int year)`.  If you can't get your compiler to complain about this, get a better (more modern) compiler.  If you can, make sure you always compile with those settings enabled. (Ugh! Pseudo-code! Ignore this!)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I probably should've mentioned this at the start, my course expects us to use the K&R style for everything as we are using ansi C and it's also what the compiler uses

Comment: Bail out from the course now — you are mislearning C. It won't be helping you if you're taught archaic C. And ANSI C is not the same as K&R C.  And which compiler are you using? An antique Borland Turbo C? (Even 'ANSI C' — presumably meaning C89 — supports the use of function prototypes; it just doesn't mandate them.  C89 allows 'implicit `int`' — but does not require it.  C99 made the implicit `int` invalid — but still allows K&R-style function definitions with types fully specified.  However, you should not use that licence to write K&R code; you should only use strict function prototypes.)

Comment: Not sure if it's a compiler but we compile everything using the Linux terminal, and the course isn't specifically to learn C, as it's a general Computer Science course.

Comment: I dunno what they're doing to you, but it sounds problematic. If you're using a modern Linux, you're using a GCC 4.x or later, which certainly has support for C99 ands probably has support for C11. You can run `cc --version` or `gcc --version` to find out which version you're using (use the same command name as you use when compiling).  And teaching you K&R-style functions is not something that's necessary for beginners.  You need to be able to recognize them eventually;  you'll come across them still, sadly.  But you should never write code using that notation unless the project requires it!

Comment: I just checked it, the version is 4.8.5, however, when compiling, we are required to write -ansi so i'm guessing it sticks to that version only.

Comment: Specifying `-ansi` is equivalent to specifying `-std=c89` or `-std=c90` (they mean the same thing).  Neither means you have to code in K&R style.  A lot of my code compiles cleanly under that standard, but none of it contains K&R-style function definitions.  (Yes, I do also have code that uses features from C99 or C11.)  You should consider using `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition …` and other options as you see fit.  (There's a chance your compiler won't accept one or both the `-Wold-*` options.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution would probably be to just let C do it.  Per [§ 6.3.1.4 of the C11 spec](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.3.1.4.html):

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero).

So, all you need to do is convert the value to an integer, than convert that back to a float:

```
float myFloor(float value) {
  return (float) (int) value;
}
```

If you need to handle negatives, you can easily do so:

```
float myFloor(float value) {
  float tmp = (float) (int) value;
  return (tmp != value) ? (tmp - 1.0f) : tmp;
}
```

Comment: I'd much prefer to just use this, but my coursework states that I need to create my own :/

Comment: What, exactly, does it say?  My guess is you just can't use the `floor()` function…

Comment: Note: this is valid for positive values only.  If it is negative, this is not a floor function.  It is also limited to the range of int.  For valid inputs of month, neither of these are problems.

Comment: It says that i'll need to write my own floor function rather than use the one in the standard C library. And yeah all the values will be positive and integers so there shouldn't be a problem with that.

Comment: The one in the standard C library is `floor()`.

Comment: Handling negatives is pretty trivial.  And you could use `int64_t` instead of int to get a larger range.

Comment: Is the one that you wrote in the comment different to the standard C library one of floor() ? I'm honestly not sure now if i've misinterpreted what was stated in the assignment or if i'm overcomplicating it.

Comment: Very different; the one in the standard C library will probably work like Shivam Sahu's answer describes.  The one I posted is quick and easy, but won't be as fully correct.  Another way to do it without diving in to implementation-specific details would be to use the `remainder()` function…

Comment: For the first approach, which values would it be that it is converting, as the algorithm is myfloor(30.6 * month - 91.4) + day , where both month and day are integers, so wouldn't it throw up some errors if it's trying to convert an the integer into an integer even though it already is one?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert-

```
float myFloor(float value) {
  return (float) (int) value;
}
```

but you can't tackle it this way. The best way of writing your own implementation is to steal the one from the C Standard Library on your platform. But note that might contain platform-specific nuances so might not be portable.

The C Standard Library floor function is typically clever in that it doesn't work by taking a conversion to an integral type. If it did then you'd run the risk of signed integer overflow, the behaviour of which is undefined. (Note that the smallest possible range for an int is -32767 to +32767).

The precise implementation is also dependent on the floating point scheme used on your platform.

For a platform using IEEE754 floating point, and a long long type you could adopt this scheme:

1. If the magnitude of the number is greater than the 53rd power of 2,
   return it back (as it's already integral).
2. Else, cast to a 64 bit
   type (long long), and return it back.

Answer (score 0):

Using floating-point for this is problematic, as floating-point arithmetic rounds results to representable values, and the rounding may cause `30.6 * month - 91.4` to produce values slightly less than 31 or 184 for `month` being 4 and 9, respectively. Then `myfloor(30.6 * month - 91.4)` would be the undesired value of 30 or 183 instead of the desired 31 or 184.

There is no need to use floating-point for this, as integer arithmetic suffices:

```
ordinal_day = (306 * month - 914 + 10000) / 10 - 1000 + day;
```

`(306 * month - 914) / 10 is mathematically equivalent to`30.6 * month -91.4`except that integer division truncates the result (effectively rounding to an integer in the direction toward zero) instead of taking the floor (rounding to an integer in the direction toward negative infinity). Since we want floor, 10,000 is added to ensure the quotient is positive, and then 1000 is subtract after the division to compensate. (If`month` could be −30 or less, further adjustment is needed, as the quotient could then be negative.)